# observableArray.remove not working correctly after manually html modified

Tags: knockout.js

Sample code is here.
https://jsfiddle.net/zLnuyk3w/4/

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
  var ids = [
    { id:50, order:1},
    { id:25, order:2},
    { id:35, order:3}  
  ];
  var list = ko.observableArray(ids);
  self.sortedList = ko.observableArray();
  ko.computed(function(){
    var computedList = list().sort(function(l, r){
        return l.order < r.order ? -1 : 1;
    });
    self.sortedList(computedList);
  });  
  self.addNewItem = function(){
    list.push({id: 40, order:2});
  }
  self.deleteItem = function(item){
    list.remove(item);
  }      
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$('tbody').sortable({
 update: function(event, ui) {
  // vm.list().updateOrder();   // somehow update 'order' property but for simplicity reason, omit the actual code
  vm.list.valueHasMutated();
 }
});
$( "tbody" ).disableSelection();
```

I basically want to sort a row of table by hand with jquery UI sortable plugin. But after sorting by hand and try to remove an item from an observableArray, remove doesn't work correctly.

I thoroughly search related problems, and it seems like I might need to rebind a view model after calling ko.cleanNode. Is that the only way to solve this problem? I actually want to avoid this approach since data I'm playing with is dynamically generated and a view uses many templates, so it's pretty complicated to pass right data for rebinding elements.

Comment: A jQuery UI sortable binding for knockout exists. Don't roll your own. https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thank you for your info. I'll look into it.

Comment: Bottom line: It is more complex than you might think at first.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much true. I learned that in a hard way with pulling my hair. haha

Comment: @Tomalak the custom binding worked very well. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: If you have working code then I'd say it's more efficient if you'd post your own answer instead of me thinking up and testing yet another working code sample.

Comment: Alright I'll post my code as answer later this week since I'm pretty busy now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tomalak said it's more complex than I thought and the custom binding he pointed me out worked very well.
https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

I'll post a sample code later.

**EDIT**
I couldn't figure out how to add a local js file to fiddler so this time is only a sample code. Refer knockout-sortable.js and it gets a job done for you. In this case, I didn't need the computed observable since an item's position in the list is actually changed by the custom binding and that's what I wanted. Of course if you want to change an order of a list with an other action, you need a computed observable for sorting most likely.

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="sortable: list" >
<tr>
  <td data-bind="text:id"></td>
  <td ><button data-bind="click:$root.deleteItem">
  delete
  </button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
  var ids = [
    { id:50},
    { id:25},
    { id:35}  
  ];
  self.list = ko.observableArray(ids);
  self.deleteItem = function(item){
    self.list.remove(item);
  }
}    
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simpler than you think, and not knockout related:

You're not returning `0` for items that have the same `order` index. Change your sort method to this:

```
return l.order === r.order ? 0 : l.order < r.order ? -1 : 1;
```

Now, when adding an item, your table at least sorts correctly. If you want to change the `order` properties dynamically, by some sort of external logic, you'll have to make them `observable`. You'll go from this:

```
self.sortedList = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return list().sort(function(l, r){
        return l.order === r.order 
          ? 0 
          : l.order < r.order ? -1 : 1;
    });
});
```

To this:

```
self.sortedList = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return list().sort(function(l, r){
        var oL = l.order(), 
            oR = r.order();
        return oL === oR
          ? 0 
          : oL < oR ? -1 : 1;
    });
});
```

Now, whenever either `list` or one of its items `order` property changes, the list is re-sorted.

If this doesn't work, or isn't what you needed, the problem is probably in the jQuery widget. If it removes elements from your html, knockout can loose its connection. (For example, if it sorts by cloning elements and reordering)

You can solve this by either writing a custom binding handler that reapplies the widget in the `update` function, or by getting rid of the plugin and using a system like I'm describing. Check out this example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  var ids = [{
    id: 50,
    order: ko.observable(1)
  }, {
    id: 25,
    order: ko.observable(2)
  }, {
    id: 35,
    order: ko.observable(3)
  }];
  var list = ko.observableArray(ids);
  self.sortedList = ko.observableArray();
  ko.computed(function() {
    var computedList = list().sort(function(l, r) {
      var lO = l.order(),
        rO = r.order();
      return lO === rO ? 0 : lO < rO ? -1 : 1;
    });
    self.sortedList(computedList);
  });
  self.addNewItem = function() {
    list.push({
      id: 40,
      order: 0
    });
  }
  self.deleteItem = function(item) {
    list.remove(item);
  }

}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: sortedList">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:id"></td>
      <td>
        <label>order:
          <input type="number" data-bind="value: order">
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, that's probably one of problems but actually even if I don't use computed sorted list, it won't work properly. And your code didn't help either sadly. Thanks anyway

Comment: Actually, in your fiddle, it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/sh6dfd4c/ I'll add some more explanation to my answer though... Hope it'll help

Comment: If the code in the edit doesn't work for you, the problem is in the jQuery plugin. If it removes data-bound elements from the DOM, knockout might loose it's connection to the table.

Comment: Thank you for your time for detailed explanation. Yes, I know if I want to sort  the list with order property, I need to make it observable, but I didn't want to do so that's why I call vm.list.valueHasMutated(); after update the order. But anyway, yeah, I agree with you, probably the jquery widget looses the knockout connection, and that's what I guessed and the reason I asked about how to rebind the items after updating the order in my question in the first place. I need that jquery widget feature, so somehow I want to re-draw items, do you think I need to use ko.cleanNode in this case?

Comment: Usually, having to use `cleanNode` is a bad sign... Have you looked for a ready made custom binding? Maybe you can provide an example that shows the actual error/problem, including the sortable library. If you can, I can have a look and provide a more precise answer...